# Fixar Coluna Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css3, layout-responsivo

Ola,

Tenho 2 colunas, uma com um col3 e uma com um col9. Gostaria que a col9 fosse fixa e a col3 tivesse rolagem.

Como posso fazer isso com bootstrap?

Comment: Quando você diz `fixa` você quer dizer sem barra de rolagem?

Comment: @Gerep, digo, tenho 2 divs, uma delas tem muito conteudo(uma lista com 100 linhas) e a outra tem apenas 1. Quero que a coluna com 1 fique fixa enquanto que a segunda desça ao ir na barra de rolagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar acrescentar o atributo "fixed" na div

Ex:

```
<div class="col3"></div>
<div class="col9 fixed"></div>
```